# "start %comspec% /c script.cmd" vs "start cmd /C script.cmd"

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

What is the difference between following commands:

```
start %comspec% /c script.cmd
start cmd /C script.cmd
```

I need that cmd window for script.cmd should close automatically when script.cmd is finished.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**`%comspec%` just points to cmd.exe**, so both commands will do the same thing. Other than that `/C` is correct, this will close the command prompt after execution

Comment: btw: if you wand to run second.cmd and script.cmd the second line wont work. it will just pass "script.cmd" as a parameter to second.cmd

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that "%comspec%" *should* expand to the default command interpreter, whereas "cmd" searches for a cmd executable and invokes it. Most of the time they are the same.

But in case there is a cmd executable (cmd.exe, cmd.bat, etc) in the current directory, than that cmd executable will be invoked.

I would go with using %comspec%

Answer (score -1):

For a not admin user on WindowsXP-SP2.

- %comspec% starts in %WINDIR%\System32.
- 'cmd' starts in user's home e.g. C:\Document And Settings\USER1.

Comment: Not completly true. `%comspec%`  is defined with an absolute path to cmd.exe, `cmd` simply search in all parts of the path variable and in  your case you have a cmd.exe also in `C:\Document And Settings\USER1`  but this shouldn't be the standard