# How to start a batch file minimized with task scheduler in Windows 8? - %comspec% method not working anymore after Windows 7

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

After Windows XP, I always use the trick below to start batch files minimized with Windows Task Manager.

From http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/running-bat-files-minimized-scheduler-t2125918.html:

> "prequisite: all your batch files have an exit-command to finish the actions off. If you do not exit, you will end with a command prompt blinking.

This is what I keep using:

```
%comspec% /c start /min "C:\Scripts\Destination_inbound_ftp5.bat"
```

When you save this in the properties, you will get a follow-up dialogue asking you if you meant all this to be parameters or not. Answer NO and the task will be saved as you would expect.

I also read the Stack Overflow question *[“start %comspec% /c script.cmd” vs “start cmd /C second.cmd script.cmd”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121238)*, which made me replace the "%comspec%" statement with "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe", but that did not change anything either.

The problem is that now, instead of a minimized running bat file, I end up with just a command prompt, minimized but without any of the batch commands executed. The task scheduler status remains "running" :(

How do I get this done on Windows 8 (64-bit)? Preferrable with old-school batch commands instead of PowerShell (or worse ;p)

Comment: There's a tick next to answers.  Make sure you accept the answer that works for you - and you can also change it later if you need to.

Comment: perhaps the simplest way to run a scheduled task in a minimized / hidden state (no flashing command-line windows) is to launch the Task Scheduler console, right-click on the task you want to run in the background and choose Properties, then enable the 'Hidden' option AND also click 'Run whether user is logged on or not'. this method will run the scheduled task silently, without opening any windows whatsoever.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The start command needs the leading `""` quotes to disable the title feature.  Try scheduling this:

```
%comspec% /c start "" /min "C:\Scripts\Destination_inbound_ftp5.bat"  ^& exit
```

Comment: Remember to add an exit code for the batch file, or the Command Prompt will stay opened after successful run.

Comment: This won't work, it will still create a console window which flashes up (and steals input focus) for a moment. It doesn't create a console window for the batch file, but it does for the `cmd` process (and the `start` command), so this isn't the same as running it in the background (i.e., no visual indication at all).

Comment: @Synetech  Thanks for your comment but it wasn't running at all for the OP due to the title requirement of the start command - and `"(i.e., no visual indication at all)."` isn't asked in the question.

Comment: See RationalRabbit's answer for making sure windows don't stack up (add "^& exit" to command parameters.

Answer (score 28):

Assuming Windows 8 is the same as Windows 7, an "exit" is only going to exit the batch file (which it is going to do anyway).

You need to add the exit code like this:

Under "Program/Script":

CMD (or command.exe, or %comspec%)

Under "Arguments:

```
/c start "Title" /min "C:\Scripts\Destination_inbound_ftp5.bat" ^& exit
```

Comment: This is probably better variant of `cmd /c start "" /min cmd /c batch.bat`.

Comment: In my case, with Windows 10, I had to add `%comspec%` at the beginning to this example work.

Answer (score 9):

I didn't like seeing the command window pop up and then disappear so here is another solution from https://ss64.com/vb/run.html ...

First create `invisible.vbs` with this single line of text:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False
```

Next and finally, launch your cmd or batch file via:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\wscript.exe "invisible.vbs" "myscript.cmd" //nologo
```

Ta da! Scripting of this sort has been built into Windows for a long time. If you're curious, do a web search for "WSH" (windows scripting host). You can even write such scripts in dialect of JavaScript called JScript.

Comment: Can you add parameters to `myscript.cmd` if needed?

Comment: This requires an extra file but is the best solution!

Comment: Neil's solution makes the command window that is being run *completely* invisible (hidden). If you just want to have it start minimized, change the parameter just before "False" to 7 instead of 0. Also see "Settings for intWindowStyle" at his provided link above for more options.

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility: a small freeware program named [CMDH](http://www.gate2.net/tools/cmdh/cmdh.html), that simply **runs the requested orders in background**.
For example:

```
cmdh MyScript.cmd
```

No need to add "exit" to the script.
Tested working in Windows XP SP3, and there is no reason it should fail on Windows 8.

Comment: Linked CMDH server is down and I can't find any other links to CMDH in google. Perhaps not too well supported.

Comment: Indeed, @fantabolous , the full site seems to be dead. I could upload it somewhere, but I think links to Google Drive or similar storage sites are not allowed by rules. Could someone please tell us about some allowed method to upload a file?

Comment: I have found it on this site: https://forum.tuts4you.com/files/file/1136-cmdh-cmd-running-in-hidden-window/

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution from https://ss64.com/vb/run.html that will run a batch file in a minimized window.  Unlike the other solutions that use the `start` command with `/min`, this one will not flash a new window onto your screen or interrupt full-screen activities.  It does, however, steal focus.  I don't know how to avoid that.

First create a file named `run_minimized.vbs` with this single line of text:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 2, False
```

Next, create your Task Scheduler task with an action to start the program `wscript.exe` with these arguments:

```
"c:\path\run_minimized.vbs" "c:\path\my script.bat"
```

Change the paths as necessary to specify the locations of the two files.

There is no simple way to pass arguments from Task Scheduler to the batch file while also preserving spaces and quotation marks, because wscript strips quotation marks from its arguments.  The simplest way to handle arguments with spaces would be to put the entire batch file command into the vbs:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run  """c:\path\my script.bat"" ""arg 1"" arg2", 2, False
```

Note the use of quotation marks.  There's one pair of quotation marks `"` enclosing the entire command string, and a pair of adjacent quote characters `""` every place you'd use a normal quotation mark in a command line.

Comment: After trying Powershell, Python, and simple batch file, this is the solution I found that worked. Its quite interesting that you simply just _can't_ run a background Powershell script without a window flashing. Its quite mind boggling, especially since Powershell is quite handy. I'm sure there are other ways, but this simple way worked for me. I was trying to do SCP, and it worked with this solution. I know that you can set Task Scheduler to run a Powershell script via "SYSTEM" user and it won't flash a PS window, I have some of those scripts. But for SCP I _had_ to use my current user.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's not the same as you mean but if I simply run a .bat file with the scheduler and tick this "Hidden" box on the General tab of the task properties it starts minified.

[image]

Comment: Nice. This checkbox is somewhat... hidden. (Not really, but rather inconspicuous.)

Comment: in addition to 'Hidden', also click 'Run whether user is logged on or not' to make the task run silently in the background.

Comment: This doesn't work with my testing, and the cmd window still pops up.

Comment: By the name, you would assume it would hide the window, but I can confirm it does not work for Windows Server 2008r2 either.

Comment: As per https://superuser.com/a/478066, ticking the 'Hidden' checkbox does not hide or minimize the program. Instead it hides the task from Task Scheduler's list of tasks. See also: Task Scheduler 'View' menu > 'Show hidden tasks'.

Comment: Works well for me on Windows 11! The cmd window used to pop up in the foreground, now it runs minimised, barely noticeable. Perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in [foxidrive](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2299431)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18885450), the issue is caused by the missing title parameter, which is taken from the first quoted argument string on the command line of the [`start` command](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html), which is the quoted batch file path in your command line. Since there is nothing left to be taken as the command/program to be started, the default `cmd.exe` is started.

Providing a dummy title (which may even be empty) solves that issue:

```cmd
%ComSpec% /C start "" /MIN "C:\Scripts\Destination_inbound_ftp5.bat"
```

However, as mentioned in the help message of `start` (type `start /?` into a command prompt window), when the provided command/program is a batch file, the [command processor `cmd.exe`](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) is run with the `/K` switch, which keeps the command prompt window open:

> ```cmd
>     command/program
>                 If it is an internal cmd command or a batch file then
>                 the command processor is run with the /K switch to cmd.exe.
>                 This means that the window will remain after the command
>                 has been run.
>
>                 If it is not an internal cmd command or batch file then
>                 it is a program and will run as either a windowed application
>                 or a console application.
> ```

To prevent that, let us explicitly specify the command processor with the `/C` switch:

```cmd
%ComSpec% /C start "" /MIN %ComSpec% /C "C:\Scripts\Destination_inbound_ftp5.bat"
```

So there is no additional [`exit` command](https://ss64.com/nt/exit.html) necessary.