# Can I run a minimised program from task scheduler?

Tags: git, windows-task-scheduler, shortcut-file, mintty, lnk

I have a sync program which runs various Git commands to update a repository. So far I have written a functioning .sh script and scheduled it to run periodically from startup.

Currently, I will be busy updating things and git bash will appear over the top of whatever I'm doing. I want the program to begin minimised. Running Windows 10, task scheduler doesn't seem to have this functionally built in.

I have tried creating a shortcut with special target parameters (as mentioned in the [Tips.md](https://github.com/mintty/mintty/blob/7d70b3cb9776de288375ffe438d35e648650c98f/wiki/Tips.md#using-desktop-shortcuts-to-start-mintty) of the [mintty GitHub page](https://github.com/mintty/mintty)) with success until I run it from the Task Scheduler. The Task Scheduler, not built on top of a command line, runs `mintty.exe` as the specified shortcut's underlying program.

When I specifically add ".lnk" to my target path (as is the file extension of this shortcut), Task Scheduler doesn't recognise it and prompts a manual selection of a program to run it in.

Ideally, I'd like every command line of any kind in each part of a solution to minimised or hidden but I'm okay with less than half a second of popup.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Hi @matt, what does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

It really isn't that difficult.

Instead of going about it in a strange way employing strange tools I'd never heard of, I tried from scratch.

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18881221/how-to-start-a-batch-file-minimized-with-task-scheduler-in-windows-8-comspec) post answered partly by @RationalRabit on the subject of a similar problem that occurred on Windows 8, by running:

> You need to add the exit code like this:
>
> Under "Program/Script":
>
> CMD (or command.exe, or %comspec%)
>
> Under "Arguments:
>
> `/c start "Title" /min "C:\Scripts\Destination_inbound_ftp5.bat" ^& exit`

I found this solution worked well when I used `/c start "Title" /min "<PATH>"`.

instead and I changed my `.sh` extension to an exact copy to `.bat`.

The moral of this story is: *If it's a Windows Tool, it's probably been around for a while.*